# Laravel default guard api - use web guard for login route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how to change the guard for a special route?

i've configured the api guard as default

```
  'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

now i've a route /login to authenticate the user with basic.once and send back the api token

```
Route::get('/login', ['middleware' => 'auth.basic.once', 'uses' => 'ApiController@login']);
```

with the following error

```
ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 288:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard' does not have a method 'onceBasic'
```

as he try to use the default api guard...

i want to keep api as default guard, just want to use web/auth.basic.once for the single /login route

*EDIT*

```
'auth.basic.once' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth::class,

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
//use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return Auth::onceBasic() ?: $next($request);
    }
}
```

this is from the laravel 5.2 documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

thanks

Comment: Can you post your middleware too ?

Comment: I think just change this `Route::get('/login', ['middleware' => ...` to this `Route::get('api/login', ['middleware' => ...`

Comment: i've wrapped all my routs in a group Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {}......

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12125) hope that help